# Hibernate ObjectNotFoundException Inconsistency

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following one-to-one (optional) relationship between two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HLTH_RQRMT")
public class Requirement
{
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "healthRequirement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private HealthRequirementSystemIdentifier requirementSystemId;

    ...
    public HealthRequirementSystemIdentifier getRequirementSystemId()
    {
        return requirementSystemId;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "HLTH_RQRMT_SYS_IDNTFR")
public class HealthRequirementSystemIdentifier
{

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Hlth_Rqrmt_Id", nullable = false)
    private Requirement healthRequirement;
}
```

After the requirement is loaded from the database, the identifier is checked:

```
//Load will always return a result (or exception) - works correctly.
Requirement requirement = (Requirement) getSession().load(Requirement.class, id);

//This is where the exception is thrown
if (requirement.getRequirementSystemId() == null)
```

When there is an identifier, the code works fine in all environments. When there is no identifier, it works fine in unit tests and locally (confirmed by testing against the production database).
When there is no identifier in production, the following error is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists:
[Requirement#250583] at
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$2.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:419) at
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:154) at
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:143) at 
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:174) at
org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190) at
Requirement_$$_javassist_66.getRequirementSystemId(Requirement_$$_javassist_66.java) at
mypackage.myclass.processResponse(MyServiceImpl.java:244)
```

I can trigger the above error in unit tests by added the property `optional=false` to the mapping annotation.

What could cause the results to be different between unit tests and production? The default value of the `optional` property is true, which is why it works correctly in unit tests.
If I add the property `optional=true`, it has no impact on the unit tests, but is it likely to fix the issue in production?

I am aware of the annotation `@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)`, but I'd prefer to understand the cause of the problem before ignoring it.

Comment: this might indicate a spurious HealthRequirementSystemIdentifier row referencing a non-existing Requirement id. Execute a select query on production to check for this inconsistency

Comment: The database would not allow that as it would violate foreign key integrity. Still, I ran the query and this is not the case. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Well, your exception tells you that hibernate cannot find a Requirement instance with @Id 250583; it might happen for other reasons besides integrity inconsistency, like concurrency or a badly caught exception, but that's rare. The stacktrace and relevant code can make the situation more clear. Which is the underlying database?

Comment: Are you sure that's what it means? When I've seen this previously, it usually means that an entity relationship cannot be retrieved from the entity with the given ID. If it couldn't find the Requirement, the line above would throw an exception (I've just added it to this question). We're using DB2.

Comment: Try to set hibernate to show generated queries. I think when you call *requirement.getRequirementSystemId()* it generates something like _select ... from HLTH_RQRMT_SYS_IDNTFR where Hlth_Rqrmt_Id = 250583_, which it does not find.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it does and what I'd expect. The problem is, the relationship should be optional, and that's how it's treated in unit tests/local code. However in production, for some reason hibernate throws an exception when that query returns no result.

Comment: ah! just use *getSession().get()* instead of *getSession().load()*! Method load() throws the exception, method get() returns null.

Comment: I've changed the code in the question to make it a bit clearer. The exception is being thrown by requirement.getRequirementSystemId(). The call getSession().load(...) works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getSession.get()` instead of `getSession().load()`

If load() can't find the object in the cache or database, an exception is 
thrown. The load() method never returns null. The get() method returns 
null if the object can't be found.

> The load() method may return a proxy instead of a real persistent
>   instance.  A proxy is a placeholder that triggers the loading of the
>   real object when it’s  accessed for the first time; we discuss proxies
>   later in this section. On the  other hand, get() never returns a
>   proxy.

Choosing between get() and load() is easy: If you’re certain the persistent 
object exists, and nonexistence would be considered exceptional, load() is a 
good option. If you aren’t certain there is a persistent instance with the given 
identifier, use get() and test the return value to see if it’s null. Using load() has 
a further implication: The application may retrieve a valid reference (a proxy) to a 
persistent instance without hitting the database to retrieve its persistent state. *So 
load() might not throw an exception when it doesn’t find the persistent object 
in the cache or database; the exception would be thrown later, when the proxy 
is accessed.*

Comment: Ah, it finally clicked, thank you. So my real problem is figuring out why it can't find an entity that is in the database. With two JVMs in paralel, caching is not my friend :(